# Using image from app package in Win10 toast

Tags: c#, windows-10, toast

I'm using [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/) guide to create Windows 10 notifications from my C# WinForms (Not WPF or UWP!) app.

I added the image to the project root and set it as an `Embedded Resource`. I then tried referencing it using `pack://application:,,,/dicon.png` and `ms-appx:///dicon.png`, neither of which worked. I believe this must be possible since the blog post says:

> Note: Images can be used from the app’s package, the app’s local storage, or from the web. Images must be less than 200 KB in size.

Could someone guide me on what I could use in place of this line to refer to my image `dicon.png`?

```
string image = "http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-71-81-permanent/2727.happycanyon1_5B00_1_5D00_.jpg";
```

Comment: I do not have a solution, but here you should see what values are allowed for the source of an image: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br230844